# Python code to transform (crop) rectangles to new smaller coordinate system

Tags: python, transform, rectangles, coordinate-transformation

[image: Transformation]

As shown in the picture, different size of rectangles are in the X0,Y0 coordinate system. Now I need to crop this window as shown in X'0 and Y'0 coordinate system. 
I need help with an algorithm in python to,

1. There could be rectangles which do not overlap with the new coordinate system at all. Get rid of them and filter out only the one which overlap even by a smaller portion.
2. As shown red in the picture, adjust the coordinates of x and y of buildings as such only the parts lying in the new coordinate system(red) become rectangles with respect to X'0 and Y'0.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have done: